ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'testxyz'
I have created a python package which has:

__init.py
setup.py

Contents of setup.py:
setup(name="testxyz",version="0.2",description="test",long_description="test",author="test",Packages=['testxyz'],install_requires=[])

Now i run
python setup.py sdist bdist_wheel
This creates the wheel file. I am able to install the wheel file using pip install. I am also able to see it in the pip list output. After this, when i run:
import testxyz, i get the below error:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'testxyz'

can you share the file structure

@AdamBasha init.py and setup.py are present within a directory named "test". When i run the python setup.py sdist bdist_wheel command, it creates a dist directory where the wheel file is created.

This is an incorrect setup, and this is why it is not working, you need to put the __init__.py in a folder named the name of your lib, then put the __init__.py inside the folder. Then it should work. This is a simple package example: https://github.com/Bashamega/py_calculator/

When you have issues with standard features of any language, it is always worth checking the official documantation for the feature you are trying to use. In this case The Python Tutorial - 6.4. Packages

@AdamBasha Correcting the directory structure solved the issue. Thanks for the help

Several things might be at issue here, however based on the information so far:

You say your file is __init.py but it should be __init__.py
testxyz needs to be a directory with __init__.py inside it.

There may also be other issues with your setup.py.
Using a dependency management tool
It looks like you are just starting out a project. In which case, I'd recommend switching to pyproject.toml instead of setuptools legacy setup.py. This is the new standard way of configuring a python project.
Secondly, rather than trying to handcraft an initial project structure. You can make use of something like pdm or poetry and a lot of the work is done for you.
pip install pdm
pdm init

You then get a folder structure auto-generated for you, with dependency management out of the box.
pdm add numpy

Updates the pyproject.toml for you with the dependencies you want.
pdm install

This creates a virtual environment for you (a sandboxed per-project Python environment). If you work on multiple projects it's worth using a venv for each, rather than trying to manage the dependencies on the system python install.
To activate the venv, you just need to "source" not execute the activate script.
source ./.venv/bin/activate

development install
You seem to be trying to build a wheel and then install that to round trip during development. You're going to get tired of this very quickly. When you build and install a wheel package it copies the contents of your source dir to "site-packages" dir. So if your code doesn't do what you expect, is it because it's not working... or is it because you're running an old version of your code because you forgot to reinstall it.
You can use develop mode for this. Which is enabled out of the box with pdm install, however you can also do it manually with:
pip install -d .

where . is the path to the directory containing setup.py or pyproject.toml. Note: if using pyproject.toml this only works with some "backends". Not sure the current state, but I think pdm works, poetry didn't but provides an equivalent.
Anyway, hope this helps get you going.
